# ffmpeg fails to capture desktop when UAC prompt appears

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to stream desktop to .avi file using ffmpeg static version 3.2.4 from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/, but streaming fails when UAC prompt appears.

Command line that I am trying to use:

```
 ffmpeg.exe -f gdigrab -analyzeduration 100M -probesize 100M -i desktop -framerate 10 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -x264opts crf=23 -r 10 "<local_file_path>.avi"
```

Output that I got:

```
  ffmpeg version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2
--enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontcon
fig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libb
luray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --e
nable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-l
ibopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libope
njpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --en
able-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enabl
e-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable
-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --e
nable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
[gdigrab @ 00000000003684a0] Capturing whole desktop as 1654x927x32 at (0,0)
Input #0, gdigrab, from 'desktop':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1494400135.425894, bitrate: 1470470 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: bmp, bgra, 1654x927, 1470470 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 1000k tbr,
 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
[libx264 @ 000000000036b3e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
AVX
[libx264 @ 000000000036b3e0] profile Constrained Baseline, level 4.0
Output #0, avi, to 'C:\New folder\test.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf57.56.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 1654x926, q
=-1--1, 10 fps, 10 tbn, 10 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (bmp (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   12 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       6kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 dro
frame=   18 fps= 17 q=12.0 size=     309kB time=00:00:00.50 bitrate=5067.3kbits/
frame=   23 fps= 15 q=14.0 size=     624kB time=00:00:01.00 bitrate=5113.2kbits/
frame=   29 fps= 12 q=13.0 size=     757kB time=00:00:01.60 bitrate=3877.8kbits/
frame=   35 fps= 12 q=12.0 size=     849kB time=00:00:02.20 bitrate=3161.9kbits/
frame=   40 fps= 12 q=15.0 size=     914kB time=00:00:02.70 bitrate=2771.9kbits/
frame=   44 fps= 11 q=17.0 size=     992kB time=00:00:03.20 bitrate=2538.6kbits/
frame=   49 fps= 11 q=11.0 size=    1069kB time=00:00:03.70 bitrate=2366.7kbits/
frame=   55 fps= 11 q=11.0 size=    1186kB time=00:00:04.40 bitrate=2207.5kbits/
[gdigrab @ 00000000003684a0] Failed to capture image (error 5)
desktop: I/O error
frame=   59 fps= 10 q=10.0 size=    1197kB time=00:00:04.80 bitrate=2043.4kbits/
frame=   59 fps= 10 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1220kB time=00:00:06.10 bitrate=1638.6kbits
/s dup=0 drop=99 speed=1.04x
video:1213kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
overhead: 0.577492%
[libx264 @ 000000000036b3e0] frame I:1     Avg QP:20.00  size:249076
[libx264 @ 000000000036b3e0] frame P:58    Avg QP:13.95  size: 17124
[libx264 @ 000000000036b3e0] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 000000000036b3e0] mb P  I16..4:  1.8%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 14.1%  0.0
%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:84.2%
[libx264 @ 000000000036b3e0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 31.5% 13.5% 12.4% inter: 7
.7% 2.1% 1.5%
[libx264 @ 000000000036b3e0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 72% 25%  2%  1%
[libx264 @ 000000000036b3e0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 71% 16% 12%  0%
[libx264 @ 000000000036b3e0] kb/s:1629.20
```

In output can see message:

```
[gdigrab @ 00000000003684a0] Failed to capture image (error 5)
desktop: I/O error
```

this is written to output when UAC prompt appears.

Am I doing something wrong or missing in command line?
Have to stream desktop using ffmpeg and don`t fail when UAC prompt appears?

Comment: if you got any solution please tell me as well . i am also suffering with this issue .thanks

Answer (score -1):

Disable UAC dim desktop option. It will resolve the issue.

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/112520-enable-disable-dimmed-secure-desktop-uac-prompt-windows.html

Comment: Can you please state your solution explicitly so your answer can be used without the external link (even though it is useful for more info).